# CONTAINED IN (@start, @end) VS BETWEEN - temporal tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

**Temporal Tables** is a new feature in `SQL Server 2016` and above , it is like an interesting way for `SQL Server` to automatically keep history of data in a table, However there are some new T-SQL syntax introduced in `SQL Server 2016` to support Temporal Tables. I faced misunderstanding of some of them.

From [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) the description of `BETWEEN <start_date_time> AND <end_date_time>` is as next:

> Same as above in the FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM  TO
>     description, except the table of rows returned
>   includes rows that became active on the upper boundary defined by the
>    endpoint.

and the description of `CONTAINED IN (<start_date_time>, <end_date_time>)` is as next:-

> Returns a table with the values for all row versions that were opened
>   and closed within the specified time range defined by the two datetime
>   values for the CONTAINED IN argument. Rows that became active exactly
>   on the lower boundary or ceased being active exactly on the upper
>   boundary are included.

so I understood, the only Different between `CONTAINED IN (@start,@end)` and `BETWEEN` clause is the `CONTAINED IN (@start, @end)` is including the @start boundary and `BETWEEN` clause is not. Am I right?

Comment: Do you asking if the `@Start` boundary is included in `BETWEEN` clause or not included?

Comment: No, I know the `@Start` is NOT including. I am asking is the next statement correct ? **The return result of CONTAINED IN is the same of BETWEEN except the CONTAINED IN is included the @Start boundary and the  BETWEEN  is not** is it right ? Thanks.

Comment: You just answer your question, the results will deferent in the two cases.

Comment: I am asking about is this the **only** difference ?

Comment: CONTAINED IN returns only those that existed within specified period boundaries. If you search for non-current row versions only, CONTAINED IN Will be the best choice as it works only with the history table and will yield the best query performance.

Comment: Many Thanks, the difference now is so clear.

Answer (score 5):

In [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5436/options-to-retrieve-sql-server-temporal-table-and-history-data/) article, [@Ameena Lalani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9052967/ameena-lalani) explains and demonstrates the various options to search a temporal table are explained very well, make sure you read the whole article.

To briefly summarize:

- `FROM <start_datetime> TO <end_datetime>`
  returns a result combing the temporal and history table, excluding the upper-boundary of the end-time.
- `BETWEEN <start_datetime> AND <end_datetime>`
  Returns a combined result from both the temporal and history tables including the upper-boundary of the end-time.
- `CONTAINED IN (start_datetime, end_datetime)`
  Returns results only from the history table and includes both the upper and lower boundaries of times.

Here's a screenshot taken from that article:

[image]